# Import data and rearranging

Tags: import

I need to `Import` datas, then I use `Import["salida.dat","Table"]` and the result is:`salida = {{1,2},,{3,4}}`. How can I remove `salida =` and have only the list and Why do this has two commas and how can I delete them?

Comment: What does `FilePrint @ "salida.dat"` return?

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
Cases[Import["salida.dat","Table"],{_,_}]
```